# I need help speeding up this EF LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework 6 and running into some major speed issues -- this query is taking over two seconds to run.  I have spent the better part of the day using LinqPad in order to speed up the query but I could only get it down from 4 to two seconds.  I have tried grouping, joins, etc. but the generated SQL looks overly complicated to me.  I am guessing that I am just taking the wrong approach to writing the LINQ.

*Here is what I am attempting to do*

1. Find all `A` where `Valid` is null and `AccountId` isn't the current user
2. Make sure the `Collection` of `B` does not contain any `B` where `AccountId` is the current user
3. Order the resulting `A` by the number of `B` in its collection in descending order
4. Any `A` that doesn't have any `B` should be at the end of the returned results.

I have to models which look like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool? Valid { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual A Property { get; set; }
}
```

The table for `A` has about one million rows and `B` will eventually have around ten million.  Right now `B` is sitting at 50,000.

Here is what the query currently looks like.  It gives me the expected results but I have to run an `orderby` multiple times and do other unnecessary steps:

```
var filterA = this.context.A.Where(gt => gt.Valid == null && !gt.AccountId.Contains(account.Id));

var joinedQuery = from b in this.context.B.Where(gv => !gv.AccountId.Contains(account.Id))
                            join a in filterA on gv.A equals a
                            where !a.Collection.Any(v => v.AccountId.Contains(account.Id))
                            let count = gt.Collection.Count()
                            orderby count descending 
                            select new { A = gt, Count = count };

IQueryable<GifTag> output = joinedQuery
                .Where(t => t.A != null)
                .Select(t => t.A)
                .Distinct()
                .Take(20)
                .OrderBy(t => t.Collection.Count);
```

Thanks

Comment: When measuring the execution time of the query, does it include the warmup time of EF or have you run another query before making the measurement? Also, is it the first time you run the specific query? I believe that EF 6 automatically builds a compiled query and this would make the first execution of each query take a bit longer.

Comment: How many rows do you have in these tables? Have you already setup some indexes? Why is AccountId string?

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables? Which columns are part of it?

Comment: @MortenChristiansen - Yeah, I run the query multiple times in LinqPad. The first time is definitely slower.

Comment: @MajoB - The dependency properties have indexes. I also added one to AccountId.  It is a string because that's how it is generated by EF Identity in the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: @JohnKalberer do you need to do gt.AccountId.Contains(acocunt.Id) instead of gt.AccountId == account.Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could always try to remove these two lines from the joinQuery

where !a.Collection.Any(v => v.AccountId.Contains(account.Id))

and

orderby count descending

the first line have already been filtered in the first Query
and the orderline, well do do the ordering on the last Query so there is no point in doing it twice

Comment: I just tried removing one of the `Contains` and it does speed up the query.  I need to make sure it is actually returning the correct rows.  For some reason I had to do the orderby multiple times or it would be out of order when I did additional queries after the grouping.

Comment: I guess this query was a lot simpler than I thought.  Moving the `Any` out of the join worked.